# Rails Faker how to create custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, faker

I'm using rspec and faker for testing and I want to add a cuestom field on faker, I had followed this instructions:

https://github.com/stympy/faker#customization

So in my rails_helper.rb I have this line:

```
Faker::Config.locale = :ca
```

And in my ca.yml under config/locales folder I have:

```
faker:
    internet:
      usefuldata: [AAAAA,BBBBB]
```

And when I made `Faker::Internet.usefuldata` it returns undefined method 'usefuldata' for Faker::Internet:Class. And I want that `Faker::Internet.usefuldata` return AAAAA or BBBBB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include what you are expecting to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faker cannot currently support customization of Internet data.

Faker supports customization only for those classes that contain the `flexible` method in their definition. Eg: The `Faker::Name` class has [the flexible method](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/3ad557cb25d442d2a10df9ab4fae90e7877da69f/lib/faker/name.rb#L3)

For customizing name, have the locale file  - for example, fr.yml - in the following format:

```
fr:
  faker:
    name:
      region: [South East Queensland, Wide Bay Burnett, Margaret River, Port Pirie, Gippsland, Elizabeth, Barossa]
```

Here, `region` is a custom field being added to `name`.

**Note:** The first level is `fr`, not `faker`.

Other classes that support customization:

- Faker::Address
- Faker::Business
- Faker::Company
- Faker::Hacker
- Faker::Team

I have [forked the repo](https://github.com/prakashmurthy/faker) and [added the ability to customize internet fields](https://github.com/prakashmurthy/faker/commit/2d53b2abf08abc73a35544c674a233821db0e3b3). You can try it out by setting the source appropriately in the Gemfile as follows:

```
gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/prakashmurthy/faker.git'
```

Not too keen on getting this merged into `faker` gem as `useful_data` doesn't seem to be a common enough data point for a lot of users.